c++ thread: wrap thread function in lambda
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
    
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int val) : val_(val) {}
    
    int val_{0};
};
    
void threadFunction(MyClass myObj) {
    // do something ...
}
    
int main() {
    MyClass obj(42);
 
    std::thread t1(threadFunction, obj); 
    std::thread t2([=]() {
        threadFunction(obj);
    });
    
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    
    return 0;
}

In thread t1, I called threadfunction directly whereas in thread t2, I put the call of threadFunction in a lambda.
Are these two ways of thread creation equivalent?

I think t1 copies obj once (the function takes it by value) and t2 copies it twice (the lambda takes a copy and the function takes it by value again).

@mch there's an extra copy (on the calling thread) in std::thread::thread, so I think both involve 2 copies

If we forget about the possibly different copy/move operations, the program behaves the same, right?

@Mathieu if you ignore the copy/move issues, then yes.

@wohlstad AlthoughthreadFunctionaccepts by value, I could still capture by reference in the lambda [&] because the copy is made in the lambda. Makes sense?

It will still copy when the thread function will be invoked on the new thread. But anyway you specifically commented about forgetting about copy/move. Is it important for you or not ? BTW - a good way to monitor copy/move operations is to to add methods for copy and move constructors, and put some prints in them. You'll see immediately what is invoked in each variant. See demo.

@wohlstad Yes. I observed that std::thread t1(threadFunction, obj)will call copy+move constructor, whereas std::thread t2([&]() {         threadFunction(obj);     })will call only copy constructor. Hence, I prefer the latter approach.

Capturing a reference and copying it inside the lambda has a race-condition: if the thread is created and invokes the lambda which will then make the copy, it's conceivable that the object has already been destructed on the main thread when (or during) the copy is made. This does NOT occur in your example because you're joining, but it might be relevant for more complex code where your main will actually continue doing other things.

@ChristianStieber that's a good point. Added a note to my answer about it.

The only difference between the alternatives is related to copies or moves of the MyClass obj object.
It can be observed by adding copy and move constructors with prints:
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int val) : val_(val) {}

    MyClass(MyClass const & other)
    {
        std::cout << "copy\n";
        val_ = other.val_;
    }

    MyClass(MyClass && other)
    {
        std::cout << "move\n";
        val_ = other.val_;
    }

    int val_{0};
};

In the first case, the std::thread constructor will make a copy of obj, and then it will be moved when the function will be invoked by the new thread.
See demo1, with output:
copy
move

In the second case, there will be an additional copy when the lambda will be executed and will call threadFunction.
See demo2, with output:
copy
move
copy

A third alternaive is the use the lambda with capture by reference.
This will reduce it to only one copy (when the lambda will call threadFunction).
See demo3, with output:
copy

Note that this third option relies on the fact that obj is not destroyed while the thread is being launched (otherwise a race condition will occue). In your case it is OK because the threads are joined while obj is still alive.
